# How to translate time zones to Canadian French?

Tags: traduction, indications-de-temps, dates

While working on a project, our translator (service) suggested we translate time zone to Canadian French. For example.

January 2, 2003 4:55 AM PDT

would become

2 janvier 2003 4:55 AM HAP

Are time zones really translated into Canadian French? If so, which time zones are translated? One source I found suggested that only the following would be translated:

PST, PDT, MST, MDT,CST, CDT, EST, and EDT

EDIT:

This would have been a better example:

August 2, 2003 4:55 AM PDT

2 août 2003 4:55 HAP

Comment: Daylight Savings in January is uncommon in Canada, to say the least.

Comment: @Montéedelait - That's a good point. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, time zones have French names and acronyms and their use is recommended by the OQLF.

Here are the official ones used in Canada:

> *HAA : Heure Avancée de l'Atlantique
>
>   HAC : Heure Avancée du Centre
>
>   HAE : Heure Avancée de l'Est
>
>   HAP : Heure Avancée du Pacifique
>
>   HAR : Heure Avancée des Rocheuses
>
>   HAT : Heure Avancée de Terre-Neuve*
>
> *HNA : Heure Normale de l'Atlantique
>
>   HNC : Heure Normale du Centre
>
>   HNE : Heure Normale de l'Est
>
>   HNP : Heure Normale du Pacifique
>
>   HNR : Heure Normale des Rocheuses
>
>   HNT : Heure Normale de Terre-Neuve*

Here is a map showing where they apply: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure_au_Canada

There is also a French name for the Central European time zone

> *HAEC : Heure Avancée d'Europe Centrale
>
>   HNEC : Heure Normale d'Europe Centrale*

Should you want a "neutral" time zone name which works whatever the language, you might use the offset from the reference time zone, e.g.:

> EST = *HNE* = UTC-5 : Universal Coordinated Time -5h = *Temps Universel Coordonné - 5 h*.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone#/media/File:Timezoneswest.PNG

The UTC acronym was chosen as a compromise between French and English speakers, the former wanting *TUC* and the latter *UCT*.

You missed to "translate" AM (actually drop AM/PM and switch to a 24h clock) and "standard" matches "*normale*", not "*avancée*" so that should be:

> *2 janvier 2003 04:55 HNP*

Comment: What is l'heure du Yukon?

Comment: @Montéedelait Je l'ai enlevé, il n'est plus utilisé.

Comment: Great information.  I have several follow up questions... Do you happen to know if these are universally applied for all French speakers? Or just French Canadians?  Also, when they are used, do they only apply to Canada? Or do they use them for their USA equivalents? (ex, is `HNE`/`HAE` used just for Quebec, or also for New York?)  And lastly, are there French abbreviations for other European time zones and/or other places around the globe? Maybe for French territories?  Thanks.

Comment: They are not really used in France and are likely to be misunderstood. We rarely use timezone acronyms here, and not even zone names. Unlike with countries like the US and Canada,in  France we rarely have to deal with timezones, mainland France and most of Europe being in the same one. When we need to specify one, we often just tell the name of the target city, e.g. *Heure de Montréal*, *Heure de New-York*, *Heure de Londres*, *Heure de Papeete* and so on.

Comment: In Québec too, we rarely have to deal with time zones all of Québec being in the same. Though your computer will be sensitive to time zones and time zone abbreviations wherever you are, whether the default language is set to English or French.

Comment: @NouLa The time settings dialog of my android phone is showing "**Heure normale d'Europe centrale**" without abbreviation. Windows shows "**(UTC+01:00) Bruxelles, Copenhague, Madrid, Paris**" and Linux with a French locale just shows "**UTC+0100**". By the way, I voted for France to stay undefinitely in UTC+2 after next DST change...

Comment: Shouldn't EST translate as HNE = UTC - 5? I was about to correct it myself, then I thought I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @NouLa you may not have to deal with it as such, but I guess more often than France or Belgium, as I can imagine for example that you have access to more USA TV programs, or are refereing more often to the USA time, being forced to mention the timezone as there's more than 1 usa time. In Europe we can generally speak of the time of country X or Y without knowing the official time zone name. To be honnest I don't even know the official name of MY timezone...

Comment: @Montéedelait Yes, my mistake, corrected.

Comment: @MattJohnson The only timezone acronym I've ever heard used in Europe is GMT, used as a fixed reference point without regard for DST. So Britain timezone's is DST, Belgian timezone's is DST+1 (even when it's UTC+2), Chicago's is DST-6 (even when it's UTC-5), and you just know to add or deduct from your own time based on those names. That's more common in my usage than "heure de Londres" or whatever, which is strongly reminiscent of the news on French TV

Comment: @LaurentS. The local cable company converts all schedules to local ones, same for the TV guides and so on. As far as messaging on my Apple products (Macbook Air, iPad, etc.) is concerned, the question is only relevant with messages from outside Québec. Most of the time, I don't bother, and when I do, I see things like -0800, -0400, +0200, with UTC implied. It only matters when I don't know who is corresponding with me. When I take a plane, let's say, with Paris as the destination, I know they are six hours ahead of us, no sweat.

Comment: Same thing for San Francisco, I have it in my head. And when I cross the US border with my car, I usually stay in the same time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Outre les recommandations officielles, la plupart des logiciels de date et heure font référence aux fuseaux horaires par les capitales ou les villes les plus emblématiques en faisant partie.

Par exemple sur mon ordinateur, le fuseau horaire est indiqué ainsi:

> CET (Paris, France)

Comment: Yes this works fine in Western Europe, where no country has split time zones and the capitals are well known. But in bigger countries with multiple time zones, many people not even knowing the names of all the provinces, territories and states, virtually nobody being able to name all the capitals, as well as not knowing which are in which time zone, you have to use the name of the time zone itself. [Seven provinces and territories in Canada]{https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/canada) have multiple zones themselves as do several states.

Comment: North America (where I live). I'm pretty much sure, I never heard anybody on the phone mentioning "time zones", in French or in English. It is always something like; "Remember, we are two hours ahead." And, of course, there is the joke "deux heures plus tard dans les Maritimes", referring to Newfie kind of wit. Same with texting, time zones are computed in the head.

Comment: Time zones really matter only in official uses. You'll see it on your electronic flight ticket, if you bother to look for it.